Protobuf linking error, undefined reference due to symbol suffix 'B5cxx11'
I'm compiling source files test.cpp(include proto.pb.h) and proto.pb.cc together to a binary file.
I download a library libProtobufLite.a, and compile with command: g++ test.cpp proto.pb.cc -Iinclude -L. -lProtobufLite --std=c++11.
But I got an error: proto.pb.cc  undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
nm libProtobufLite.a | grep "EmptyString" shows that symbol name in library is
_ZN6google8protobuf8internal12kEmptyStringB5cxx11E
while the symbol in proto.pb.o is
_ZN6google8protobuf8internal12kEmptyStringE
my gcc version is
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-7.5.0/configure --prefix=/root/init_server/install --with-dwarf-2 --disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (GCC)

I try to add -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 to comiling command, but it doesn't work.
How to compile my source files and link to that library?
--- update ---
I tried a new gcc toolchain, /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++, but I got the same problem (with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 in compiling command).
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-7.3.1-20180303/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC)

--- update ---
After upgrading gcc to gcc 8.5.0, this problem solved.
I experimented with three scenarios. I'm curious why Case2 fails

Case 1. gcc 7.5.0 with configure--disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi and compiling option -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 : failed
Case 2. gcc 7.3.1 with configure--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible and compiling option -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1: also failed
Case 3. gcc 8.5.0 without any abi configure or compiling option: succeed


I cannot tell why it fails for you because I don't have your installation, but normally it shouldn't fail. Look here. See how GCC emits either TEST[abi:cxx11] or simply TEST depending on the option? You can try and reproduce this on your machine with your compiler. If you see TEST with either option, it means your compiler is somehow built without c++11 ABI support, config parameters notwithstanding.


--disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi
Disable support for the new, C++11-conforming implementations of std::string, std::list etc. so that the library only provides definitions of types using the old ABI (see Dual ABI). This option changes the library ABI.

That GCC 7.5.0 is configured so it cannot be uses with the downloaded libProtobufLite.a that is built with the modern ABI. You should build this library from the sources.
The _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro does not help, because it's impossible to switch on something that is not available.
